# Matplotlib 3d Plot Colorbar Scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I have a 3d plot with a colorbar and I would like the colorbar's size to scale with the size of the projection, no matter the orientation I select with `ax.view_init`.

It would also be great if I could get the aspect ratio of the 3d plot to be equal at the same time as well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=0)

x = np.arange(3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.ones_like(X)

V = np.array([[3,2,2],[1,0,3],[2,1,0]])

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=plt.cm.jet(norm(V)), shade=False)

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=norm)
m.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(m)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

Example code stolen shamelessly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924993/colorbar-for-matplotlib-plot-surface-using-facecolors)

[image: The problem]